# User Defined Functions Not Implementing HoldForm in list of Functions

Tags: functions, syntax, map, hold

When I insert the following code in Mathematica,

```
f[x__] := Map[HoldForm, {x}];
g[x_] := x^2;
f[g[t], Cos[t], Tan[t]]
```

I get `{t^2, Cos[t], Tan[t]}`, but I am trying to get `{g[t], Cos[t], Tan[t]}`. Why is `HoldForm` evaluating the user defined function `g[t]`? Any fix to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The sample code has two evaluation leaks that need to be plugged.

The first is when the arguments are passed to `f`.  `f[x]` evaluates `x`, and then `f` does its thing.  The fix for this is to give `f` the `HoldAll` attribute.

The second is when the arguments are passed to `Map`.  It's probably best to not change the attributes of `Map`, so instead we'll use `Unevaluated` to temporarily prevent evaluation until things get into `f`.

```
In[14]:= SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
In[15]:= f[x__] := HoldForm /@ Unevaluated[{x}]; 
In[16]:= g[x_] := x^2; 
In[17]:= InputForm[f[g[t], Cos[t], Tan[t]]]

Out[17]//InputForm= {HoldForm[g[t]], HoldForm[Cos[t]], HoldForm[Tan[t]]}
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem in the example that I have provided, it doesn't fix the issue of the program that I am working with. The piecewise function that I had defined in replacement of `g[t]` always self-evaluates and I am not sure why.